# How to save data offline in flutter

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart, mobile-application

I am new to Mobile development and I am now developing a quiz app in flutter.
I have created a place where users can go to statistics screen but the question is,

How can I save and retrieve the result sheet, also update the scores offline.

Can you please suggest me any links or any methods to make it successful.

Comment: Your question is quite verbose, you should try the direct tutorial on flutters official page, it's very straight forward.

https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/sqlite

Answer (score 2):

Your question is quite verbose, you should try the direct tutorial on flutters official page, it's very straight forward.
Note: this is probably not the only answer(suggestion) you need, this is just to show you how to save the quiz data on the device.

So, you probably want to break your question into pieces and compile the answers given.

https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/sqlite.

Answer (score 2):

For caching in flutter you can use any of the following library that satisfies your use-case:

1. hive : https://pub.dev/packages/hive
2. shared_preferences : https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences
3. sqflite : https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite
4. moor: https://pub.dev/packages/moor

I hope this helps, in case of any doubt please comment.